# CosmosDb as trigger for Logic apps

Tags: architecture, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

Can we use CosmosDb as trigger for Logic apps? I need a solution where if there is any change in the CosmosDB , my logic app should fire. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I check the official documentation and it seems that there is no [cosmosdb trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/documentdb/) available.

If possible, you can use the [cosmosdb trigger in the azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function), and then call the azure logic app. In this case, the azure logic app needs to use http trigger.